# Query a list of documents in firestore using an array

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Is is possible to query a list of documents in firestore using an array of IDs?

```
const UserIDs = ['zHYYvrVPLA9LOV6edwOrQhQLt6k1', 'JhUvvrNbfD9LOV6edwOrQhQLt8Gf'
'] //each ID in the array is an existent document id in the collection Users

const selectedUsers = await firestore().collection('Users').doc(UserIDs).get();
```

selectedUsers.data() is undefined despite that the documents with the given IDs exists. I know I can perform a loop, I was just wondering if the way I tried is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) and the [`FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid) function to build a query that can get up to 30 documents by their ID.

Something like:

```
firestore().collection('Users')
  .where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', UserIDs)
```

Comment: It seems to be 30 documents for IN and 10 for NOT IN according to the docs.

Comment: Good catch. The limit was increased from 10 to 30 when support for OR conditions was added. I updated my answer.